# C++ global object variable memory release

Tags: c++

Is it safe to call `test(s2)` ?  Will the memory of `test(s1)` be released? If not, any suggestion?

```
#include <string>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

nlohmann::json global;

void test(const std::string& js_string){
    global = nlohmann::json::parse(js_string);
}

int main(){
    std::string s1 = "true",s2 = "[]";
    test(s1);
    test(s2); // Is there a memory leak here? If so, how to free the memory?
    work_loop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Memory leaks appear due to missing `delete` statements to their corresponding `new` calls. I can't spot any `new` in your code, so why are you suspecting a memory leak? Also you can inspect your program using valgind or a similar too to check if there are any memory leaks.

Comment: I just want to know whether the memory usage will increase to very large. If I have quite a lot of call to `test()` and let it runs for days.

Comment: @Kishimo -- I see objects being created, assigned to, and destroyed.  Why would you expect memory usage to increase?  There are way more complex C++ programs than yours that run 24 hours a day, 7 days a week, that do not suffer from memory issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm a beginner c++. I used to write python etc.  I rewrite a C program to C++ and add `nlohmann::json` library. So just some questions. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Kishimo -- The author(s) of `nlohmann::json` are more than likely competent C++ programmers who know how to write classes that properly clean up the memory.  You must always assume that classes written not by you are written correctly in this manner unless you find out the class isn't written that way (if you did find this, and it was not documented that the library can leak memory, drop using that library immediately as it was written by non C++ programmers or rank beginners).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just find that `nlohmann::json` is as easy as in python. All my code is mainly some C function call to operating system, I need to maintain some states, so I just pick up `nlohmann::json` so I donot need to write complex struct. That's the case.  I don't know much about C++, I just write the code as in question and ask the question here.

Comment: @Kishimo -- My point is that you shouldn't doubt if a third-party library written by solid C++ programmers has memory issues.  If you're not calling `new` and `delete`, and all you're doing is using third-party libraries and making library calls, then assume the program has no leaks.  If there are leaks, it is a bug in the library you're using and you report it to the authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
global = nlohmann::json::parse(js_string);
```

Reassigns the global to have a new value. The only way this could leak anything is if the assignment operator for `nlohmann::json` is faulty.

I suspect that's not the case. You don't need to worry about leaks.

Answer (score 1):

If either `test(s1);`, `test(s2);` or `work_loop` throw an exception then process may get terminated without calling destructor for `global` (and for both strings as well) because there is no exception handling. This won't really cause a memory leak since the process memory will be reclaimed by the system anyway, however if cleanup involves other actions (e.g. removing temp files or closing net connections) it may cause real problems.

Comment: Exactly. It's not a leak if memory usage is constant.